# Disable scroll while waiting to for scroll selection animation to complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to make customize `section-scroll` where scroll event is disabled while animation is in motion.
I tried with overflow hidden and other similar functions to apply while scroll animation is in progress but no luck.

[JS fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/rkv1ehqz/1/)

**CSS**

```
.stop-scrolling {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

**JS example:**

```
$('html').on('wheel', function(event) {
  if (event.originalEvent.deltaY > 0) {
//scroll down
    counter++;


    $('body').addClass('stop-scrolling');
    console.log("Start animacije");
    setTimeout(function () {
      $('body.stop-scrolling').removeClass('stop-scrolling');
      console.log("End animation");
    }, 800);



    if (!(counter > maxSections)) {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $("#sect-"+counter) ).offset().top
      }, 800);
    }

  } else {
//scroll up
    counter--;


    $('body').addClass('stop-scrolling');
    console.log("Start animation");
    setTimeout(function () {
      $('body.stop-scrolling').removeClass('stop-scrolling');
      console.log("End animation");
    }, 800);


    if (!(counter < 1)) {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $("#sect-"+counter) ).offset().top
      }, 800);
    }

  }

  if (counter <= 0) {
    counter = 1;
  }
  else if (counter >= 3) {
    counter = maxSections;
  }

  console.log(counter);
});
```

If you scroll while animation is in progress, scroll will continue until you reach end of sections.

Is possible to disable scroll event while animation is in progress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's simple fix with less code modification.

Just declare a variable that represents scrolling state. And using this state you can ignore incoming scroll events if currently scrolling.

```js
let scrolling = false;

$('html').on('wheel', function(event) {
  if (scrolling) {
    return;
  } else {
    scrolling = true;
    setTimeout(function () {
      scrolling = false;
    }, 800 /* animation duration */);
  }

  ...
```

Here's final [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/vbkadre6/1/).

Using `setTimeout` function you can reset scrolling state to `false` so, new events will be received.

Comment: This is exacly what I was looking for, works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using CSS, you can use your script to [block scroll events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770025/how-to-disable-scrolling-temporarily).

You can use the [`onComplete` parameter of the `.animate` method](https://api.jquery.com/animate/) to run a callback after animation ends.

With this, you can use a flag variable to determine whether or not the page is scrolling.

The whole process would be something like:

1. Animation started.
2. Flag animating = true.
3. Block scrolling.
4. Animation ended.
5. Flag animating = false.
6. Unblock scrolling.

Here's a minimal and reproducible example. It may have some bugs, but it should solve your main problem.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  'use strict';
  
  // Flag to decide whether or not scroll is allowed.
  let animating = false;

  $(window).on('scroll', (e) => {
    if (animating){
      // Block scroll
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
  
  $('.section').on('wheel', e => {
    e.stopPropagation();
  
    // Do not run this function again when animation is happening.
    if (animating){
      return;
    }
  
    const $target = $(e.target);
    const isScrollDown = e.originalEvent.deltaY > 0;

    // Choose whether to scroll to next or previous section.
    const $targetSection = isScrollDown ? $target.next('.section') : $target.prev('.section');
    // Check whether or not there is a target
    const hasTargetSection = $targetSection.length > 0;

    // Only animate when there is a target.
    if (hasTargetSection){
      // Flag animation start
      animating = true;
      $('html, body').animate(
        // Animation properties
        {
          scrollTop: $targetSection.offset().top
        },
        // Animation duration
        800,
        // Function to run after animation ends
        () => {
          // Flag animation ended
          animating = false;
        }
      );
    }
  });

});
```

```css
html, body, #app {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 3em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.a {
  background-color: #f008;
}

.b {
  background-color: #0f08;
}

.c {
  background-color: #00f8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="section a">Section A</div>
  <div class="section b">Section B</div>
  <div class="section c">Section C</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking for is called throttling. I recommend you read [this link](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/debouncing-and-throttling-a4b18b0cb55d) to understand it better.

So to fix your code, you only need to enable throttling for your `wheel` event listener.

Like this:

```js
let throttle = (fn, timedelay) => {
  let pass = true;
  return function () {
    if (pass) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        fn.apply(this, arguments);
        pass = true;
      }, timedelay);

      pass = false;
    }
  };
};

let scrollFunction = throttle(function(event) {
  // your code
}, 200); // 200 miliseconds sounds good

$('html').on('wheel', scrollFunction);
```

Here is a working code: https://jsfiddle.net/d1fcL5en/